# Up navigation to swap between activities doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, up-navigation

My app basicly contains **two activities**, a **main-activity** and a **settings-activity**.

Settings-activity is launched by

```
Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent, 0);
```

, which contains some fragments. I use the **up navigation**, which works perfectly in settings-activity between the fragments, but however I **don't return to my main-activity** when pressing the back button. The setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled command is in my settings-activity, bc it didn't helped to solve my problem when I positioned it in my main-activity.

In my manifest I've declared main-activity as the **parent activity** for settings-activity.

**So what do I have to do? - lot's of thanks!**

My Mainactivity

```
package user.example;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent, 0);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

My SettingsActivity: (I've left out the fragments, but the same error is reproduced)

```
package user.example;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
           actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

AppCompatPreferenceActivity: (started by Settings.activity)

```
package user.example;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        getDelegate().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Manifest entries.

Comment: Please Post your onOptionsItemSelected() Implemention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I had to put this code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

into my AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java, now everything wokrs, thanks for all help so far!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the "main Activity" as the Parent Activity to "Settings Activity" in the Mainfest like that

```
  <activity android:name=".SettingActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

**Edit**
You neeed to add in the Setting Activity

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home) {
        finish();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately mainactivity is allready declared as the parent activity :/

Comment: did you implmented onOptionsItemSelected() if yes can you attach the code

Comment: yes, onOptionsItemSelected() is implemented in both activities

Comment: Well, I allready had a similar piece of code in settingsactivity, which I forgot to paste in, bc I though it wasn't necesary, but nothing changes, if I insert the finish(); instead of my code